# SQL - Return the Running Total (using the latest total number)

Tags: sql, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Suppose I have a table below

```
ID   SUB_ID   YEAR  Month  Value
A1   A101      1      1     100
A1   A101      1      2     100
A1   A101      2      1     100
A1   A101      2      2     100
B1   B101      1      1     200
B1   B101      1      2     200
B1   B101      2      1     200
B1   B101      2      2     200
B1   B102      2      1     300  (So this B102 is a new record starting in YEAR 2 MONTH 1)
B1   B102      2      2     300
```

And I want get the running sum per ID using the latest total number. The output should be:

```
ID  YEAR  RUNNING_SUM
A1    1      100 
A1    2      100 (for A1, there is no value change or no new SUB_ID, so the sum is always 100)
B1    1      200
B1    2      500 (in YEAR 2, B102 was added)
```

How can we achieve this? Basically I am appending the value per ID if there is new SUB_ID coming in. This would be easy in Tableau using LOD calculation (Fixed ID)

Here is SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95b63d/1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select id, year, sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, sub_id, year order by month desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by id, year
```

Comment: thank you! I applied the logic in the real-world case and it does work